# Cannot Restrict AWS Regions in my Account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to disable all but one region in an AWS account. I have followed the instruction in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment.html#disable-region) precisely.

[image: Disable Region Instructions]

Following these instructions leads me to this list of regions.

[image: Region List is not Editable]

Unfortunately, (Hong Kong notwithstanding) none of the regions in this list appear to be editable in any way. In other words, I cannot disable any of these regions. My goal is to have an account where only one region (us-west-2) is usable.

How can I accomplish this? The documentation seems to be incorrect or incomplete.

Note: This AWS Account is part of an Organization and it is not the root account of the Organization. This may be a source of discrepancy between my setup and the documentation.

p.s.: I just noticed that the documentation says "Not all regions can be disabled." I previously thought this meant "you cannot disable all regions" but I guess it means that there are regions which cannot be disabled.

So I guess the question becomes, how can I disable all but one region, for all services and actions using a policy? What would that policy JSON look like? I tried but could not come up with a valid policy.

Answer (score 2):

Only new regions (launched March 2019 or later) can be enabled/disabled at this time.

It's always been possible to restrict regions by setting up a policy condition, e.g.,:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Region": "eu-central-1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine if limiting for just one service, but is a pain if we want to limit many services since the condition we specified (`ec2:Region`) is only valid for EC2 actions.

Since last year, there's a new way to control access across many services using `aws:RequestedRegion`.  Here's an example from AWS documentation limiting some EC2, RDS and Lambda actions to one specific region:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:CreateDBCluster",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See the [AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/) for the full policy example.

Comment: From the Organization management create policy page I get "The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type." for the json you provided.

Comment: When I try to create a policy with json at my account -> security credentials -> policies, I get "This policy contains the following error: A managed policy must have a version string For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies"

Comment: What was listed in the 2nd example was just an excerpt of a Statement, not the entire policy; typically you'll want to add other statements to the full policy.  You can simply include it as a Statement in a policy (see updated answer) but see the linked AWS Security Blog entry to get a fuller picture.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official, complete answer.  Adapt the list of regions per your needs.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "DenyAllOutsideRegion",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotAction": [
            "aws-portal:*",
            "iam:*",
            "organizations:*",
            "support:*",
            "route53:*",
               "budgets:*",
               "waf:*",
               "cloudfront:*",
               "globalaccelerator:*",
               "importexport:*",
            "sts:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {"StringNotEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": [
            "us-east-1",
            "us-west-2"
        ]}}
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllRegionsOutsideN.California",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": "iam:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-west-1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add some description to your answer, not only code.